# Protovis Jquery Tooltip problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, protovis, jquery-tooltip

I would like to display data using Jquery tooltip in my web application.

I have followed the example on this website http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html and have managed to display out a tooltip on a picture on my application.

However, I am generating some bulletchart using Protovis now and would like to display out the data when I mouse over on the bullet chart.

I want to know how do I edit to make the tooltip appear? Currently I am able to display using html tags, but what I really want is to display the tooltip using javascript code.

Below my codes for bullet chart:

```
var vis = new pv.Panel()
            .data(patientData)
            .width(140)
            .height(20)
            .right(10)
            .bottom(20)
            .left(5);

            var bullet = vis.add(pv.Layout.Bullet)
            .orient("left")
            .ranges(function(d) d.ranges)
            .measures(function(d) d.measures)
            .markers(function(d) d.markers);

            bullet.range.add(pv.Bar);
            bullet.measure.add(pv.Bar)
            .fillStyle("black")
            .text(function(d) "Current Month: "+ d.toFixed(1)+"%")
            .tooltip(); -->This give me an error!
```

Would appreciate any inputs. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to chain a jQuery function, `.tooltip()`, on a Protovis object, in this case a `pv.Bar`. That's not going to work. A couple of options:

- If you're willing to change your jQuery plugin, you could probably follow [this example](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/tipsy.html), which uses [Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/).
- You could adapt the `pv.Behavior.tipsy` code [shown here](https://github.com/mbostock/protovis/blob/master/examples/tipsy/tipsy.js) to use tooltip() instead. It looks like you could do this pretty easily, just by editing lines 33 and 64 to use a different plugin - the hard work in this code is creating a `div` element to attach the tooltip to, and that's the same for both plugins.

Comment: I have managed to implement tipsy on the bulletchart. However, the tooltip's arrowhead is not being displayed. It's showing me as a circle now without the arrowhead displaying. Any idea where do I go to enable the tipsy arrowhead for display?

Comment: @Dane - That's pretty much impossible to answer without seeing code, and it's really a separate question - I'd ask a new question rather than trying to go back and forth via comments.